# Auth as "user" in SDK Node Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase-admin in Node.js to connect with the real time database. In my project, I have created some RESTful APIs but I can't achieve something.

I need to authenticate as user with a token ID that I receive as param to connect with the database and try to "get or push" information.

In this way, the rules of the database are responsible for verifying whether the user has permission or not for the action.

Is it possible to do this? Is there another alternative to verify if a user has the permissions for an operation in the database?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this.  If you're getting an ID token from the client, you'll have to use the Firebase Admin SDK to [verify that token and obtain a uid from it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk).

With that uid, you will have to initialize another instance of the Admin SDK with a service account and tell it to scope the connections made by that admin instance to the requested uid.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges) illustrates how to do this.